# What precautions to take when upgrading from lxc-docker to docker-engine?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, docker

I currently have `lxc-docker-1.4.1` installed in my ubuntu 14.04.

I want to upgrade to the latest docker.

The official docker docs on upgrading will install package `docker-engine`.

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Should I remove lxc-docker manually? Will it preserve my `/var/lib/docker` installed images ? Will it be backward compatible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Ubuntu 15.04 machine, I managed to upgrade from 1.6 to 1.8 by first removing docker and then installing. Seemed to work fine and my images were still there.

As a precaution though, I created backups of all my installed images. I followed the instructions from ["Docker container: Backup and Recovery"](http://linuxconfig.org/docker-container-backup-and-recovery) guide.

However, on my Ubuntu 14.04.3 machine, after upgrading, the docker daemon wouldn't start. The error was "`[graphdriver] prior storage driver "aufs" failed: driver not supported`".

I found that deleting the `/var/lib/docker/aufs` directory and `/var/lib/docker/repositories-aufs` file sorted out the problem, and the daemon started fine. Nothing was lost.

Comment: Thanks. I did a backup first as per your advice. Things are hunky dory now.

Comment: You can also install `linux-image-extra` to get aufs.

Comment: I manually installed kernel 4.4 on ubuntu 14.04 and also had to remove the mentioned file + directory to make docker start again.